# Ошибка (HY000/1045) при работе с БД в Open Server

Tags: php, база-данных, openserver

[image: Сама ошибка при запуске сайта]
[[image: Код с помощью которого устанавливаю соединение с сервером2]
[[image: При этом в командной строке всё хорошо, пароль подтверждается][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3NIi.png)

Ошибка:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Users\Public\OpenServer\domains\mysite.local\inc\gbook.inc.php on line 8

Объясните в чем проблема. Уже и пробовал пересоздать пароль и вводить просто root как пароль(но тогда выбивает ошибку, что неверный пароль в самой командной строке). Сижу только над этой задачей уже дня 3.

Comment: что отображает error?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Users\Public\OpenServer\domains\mysite.local\inc\gbook.inc.php on line 8 как убрать ошибку

Comment: добавляйте информацию ввиде текста: код, ошибки, конфигурации и прочее

Comment: Код в файле:
<?php

 $DB_HOST = "localhost";
 $DB_LOGIN = "root";
 $DB_PASSWORD = "password";
 $DB_NAME = "gbook";
 $connection = 
        mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_LOGIN,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_NAME);
 mysqli_connect_errno();
 mysqli_connect_error();
?>

Ошибка, которая выбивается при запуске сайта:
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Users\Public\OpenServer\domains\mysite.local\inc\gbook.inc.php on line 8

Comment: @KristapsTunnis А Вы меняли пароль от mysql в Open Server?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Да, менял

Comment: @KristapsTunnis добавляйте через ссылку [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1293434/edit) под вопросом